# Using QGIS Field calculator with geometry operations between layers

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, geometry

I am looking for making a Field calculation with QGIS, I see is possible to include the geometry field of the same feature layer, nevertheless I was wondering if it is possible to use the geometry from other layers features in my calculation. For example, intersection or else.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Should be possible, the [`get_feature()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#get-feature) function enables you to access features from any layer.

In combination with the [`geometry()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id27) function you may obtain the features geometry for spatial relationship analyses etc. `geometry(get_feature(...))`.

Key challenge in my opinion is a clever selection of the features depending on the processed dataset:

[image]